# Rails 5 git pull giving error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git

Hey I am trying to pull my changes to server I am using ubuntu server. When I am trying to run git pull I am getting this error:

```
e error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
Gemfile.lock
Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can merge.
Aborting
```

I have tried git reset --hard and then pull again I am getting this error When I am trying to remove file Gemfile.lock using rm -rf Gemfile.lock it is not removing the file. I don't know how to make git pull work.

Answer (score 1):

Follow these commands and you will be good to go

```
git stash
git pull origin <branch_name>
git stash pop
```

This will do the job.
Let me know if you still facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: if you want to set aside the changes you have made from previous commit

```
git stash
git pull
```

if you want to have the state prior to pulling (may cause merge conflict), proceed to:

```
git stash apply
```

Option 2: if you want to apply the changes you've made from previous commit

```
git commit -m "I edited this blahblah file"
git pull
```

> e error: Your local changes to the following files would be
>   overwritten by merge: Gemfile.lock Please, commit your changes or
>   stash them before you can merge. Aborting

is because you have changes in the tracked files that is not committed yet. So git wants you to commit it first (if you want to keep your changes from previous commit) or put your changes to a temporary location (stash) so that the state will go back to previous commit

Comment: I am getting : error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
 Gemfile.lock
This when I git pull and git stash apply